# How to add image to post programmatically?

Tags: wordpress

I defined image dimensions in media (WP) and in functions.php addedd some 2 custom dimensions for image upload. When I upload images through WP admin everything is ok.

But now I have client which is uploadin 100 images via FTP to some folder on his site and I was wondering if there is a way to add this image to post programmatically?

Every image has name like post_ID.jpg (for exam. 450.jpg) and this is how I will know which image to add to which post but my question is how to add programmatically with wp functions (resize/crop (like it does when i add via WP admin)).

This images are in custom folder: /product_images/

Thank's for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved..

here is a solution:

```
$post_id = 809; // example post_ID
$filename= '/my_images/809.jpg';
$description = 'some description';

# remove all attachments
$wpdb->query("UPDATE post_parent ='0' WHERE post_type='attachment' AND post_parent='".$post_id."'");

# upload / resize / crop image (to WP images folder)
media_sideload_image($filename,$post_id,$description);

$last_attachment = $wpdb->get_row($query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A);
$attachment_id = $last_attachment['ID'];

# set featured image
add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);
```

Comment: just a notice - i used this manyy times - under some scenarios the _thumbnail ID will not be the last to be uploaded .. just a heads up .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen - in sthi script it will be.

Comment: you can get rid of two lines by doing this:
$attachment_id = media_sideload_image($filename, $post_id, $description, 'id');